# The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: iis, deployment

I just deployed a website into IIS 7 (about which I am woefully ignorant), and upon trying to build the site, I receive this error.  I did a little googleing and I saw an article that said I should put system.web.extensions.dll into the /bin.  But, I also saw an article saying not to do that.  I tried it anyway, but I just received a different error ('Resource cannot be found').
I am totally clueless as to what else to try

Comment: How did you deploy the site? Is this site running on your development machine? Are you sure that .NET 3.5 is installed on that system?

Comment: I copied the entire directory to the client's server, then added a new site in IIS and pointed it to the directory.  It was running just fine here on my development machine, and yes, 3.5 is installed on the server.

Comment: Also, I tried installing / uninstalling / reinstalling the AJAX control toolkit, including restarting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the "Publish" command in Visual Studio to publish directly to the site? If not, then use that command to publish to a similar site on your machine, then copy it to the customer site.

You should also look into the [IIS Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/). It can copy an entire site, including IIS settings and any databases. It will be built into VS2010.

Comment: I'll try that, although I'm connected to their server via VPN, so I don't know if that complicates the process any...

Comment: the vpn connection is super slow, still copying the site over...  will update when it's completed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel, then programs, turn windows features on or off, scroll down to Microsoft.net framework 3.5.1 expand, make sure both sub options are selected, this might help your issue.

Comment: Ok, so when I look in installed programs, I see .net 3.5 SP1.  However, when I went in to add windows features, I only see an option for .net 3.0.  I did what you suggested anyways, I enabled the options underneath this node, (WCF Activation) but I am still getting the same problem...
Maybe I will try uninstalling / re-installing 3.5